# Internet Explorer P3P Issues! Help!

Tags: p3p

I'm having issues getting the privacy icon to go away in IE7 & IE8 and have spent 10+ hours trying different things and nothing seems to work.  Everything I try seems to lead to the same result.

I created a P3P document from the IBM tool and got it fully validated at http://www.w3.org/P3P/validator.html.  Can you think of any reasons why the privacy icon would still display if I have passed the validator?  Any help is REALLY appreciated!!!

Comment: Can you post a link to your website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just loaded your website in IE8 on Windows 7 in "High" security mode and do not see any privacy icons.  Furthermore, when I go into the Privacy Report in the browser for your website it correctly shows a summary of both privacy statements (basic information and cookies).  As far as I can tell, your P3P document is configured and being served properly.

Have you tried clearing out your browser cache in case it's loading old P3P documents?

Comment: Once I cleared the cache it went away and hasn't came back. :)